# Access to ViewModel from Service

Tags: android, mvvm

I want to create a music player app by using MVVM. most examples on the internet are not using this architecture. I run MediaPlayer in a Service. I have two questions. Can I access the Service in Fragment directly to change the MediaPlayer state or music? Can I Access ViewModel from the Service to get music files, delete the file, or other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can i access to Service in Fragment directly for change MediaPlayer state or music?

[Yes](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services).

> Can i Access to ViewModel from Service to get music file, delete file or other?

I mean, I guess you *could* - it's your code, you can do whatever you want. But you probably shouldn't. "ViewModel" is, by definition a model of the view layer. A Service is not in the view layer. You probably want to access and manipulate your files via a *repository*. Google "Android repository pattern". Your ViewModel would then also use the repository to manipulate the data from the view layer (Fragment / Activity)

Comment: Thanks, no i want get next music file when notification forward action clicked. files are in viewmodel and notification action target is service

Comment: OK. That doesn't change my answer. Move the files from the view model to a repository, then access the repository from both the view model and the service.